# Get summary count of all patches applied to a server?

Tags: centos, yum, statistics

Is there an easy way to get a count of the total number of patches applied to a server over a time frame, or even in summary?

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others:

```
$ sudo yum history summary
```

provides a list of total upgrades and installs over various time periods.  [Reference](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/yum-history-list-info-summary-repeat-redo-undo-new/).

#### Example

```
$ sudo yum history summary
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-packagekit, tsflags
Login user                 | Time                | Action(s)        | Altered 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sam Mingo <slm>            | Last day            | Install          |        1
Sam Mingo <slm>            | Last week           | I, U             |       58
Sam Mingo <slm>            | Last 2 weeks        | Install          |       22
Sam Mingo <slm>            | Last 3 months       | E, I, O, U       |     2487
System <unset>             | Last 3 months       | Install          |        1
Sam Mingo <slm>            | Last 6 months       | E, I, O, U       |     1435
System <unset>             | Last year           | Install          |     1169
history summary
```